# haskell, is IO Monoid associativity broken?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, io, monads, monoids

In haskell IO type has instance of Monoid:

```
instance Monoid a => Monoid (IO a) where
    mempty = pure empty
```

if I have three actions which share some state, and change behavior of each other via side effect, this can lead to breaking associativity law, from IO type point of view:

```
a1:: IO String
a2:: IO String
a3:: IO String
```

(a1 `mappend` a2) `mappend` a3 /= a1 `mappend` (a2 `mappend` a3)

for example if a1,a2,a3 request current time in string, or IO contains some DB which counts for request number. This mean that it can be:

```
(a1 `mappend` a2) `mappend` a3  == "1"++"2"++"3"
a1 `mappend` (a2 `mappend` a3) == "3"++"1"++"2"
```

EDIT:

I think I shouldn't have given an example with a db, it confused,
more preferred example:

```
a1 = show <$> getUnixTime 
a2 = show <$> getUnixTime
a3 = show <$> getUnixTime

l = (a1 `mappend` a2) `mappend` a3
r = a1 `mappend` (a2 `mappend` a3)
liftA2 (==) l r
**False**
```

So why IO type is monoid if it can break associativity law? or I missing something?

Comment: You think in terms of calling order, but due to laziness, that does not mean that `a1` will run last in the second case.

Comment: I think in terms of getting final result, due network latency or problems with DB it can be in any order.

Comment: Why not bring up the definition of `mappend` (as `(<>)`)? It's also vital to undertanding what's happening here.

Comment: @Evg: but `IO` (conceptually) does not *run* anything. An `IO` is a recipe to do something. You "sew" everything together into a huge recipe, and then this runs.

Comment: Also note that monoids aren't necessarily commutative. `m1 <> m2` is not necessarily the same as `m2 <> m1`, so the left-to-right order *matters*. Whether you think of this as combining `m1` and `m2` before combining the result with `m3`, or combining `m1` with the result of combining `m2` and `m3`, the end result is the same: an IO action that executes `m1`, then `m2`, then `m3`, in that order.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I edit the question, your comment with "IO recipe" helps a little bit, we comparing actions not results, yes synthetically the recipes are the same, but how can we consider these actions equal if they produce different result.. and If I try to test IO monoid associativity (liftA2 (==) l r) see in appended example with time it gives me False..

Comment: @Evg: of course it does. The recipe does not say anything about the result, but the merging of recipies guarantees *order*, so your `a1`, `a2` and `a3` will, both in `l` and `r` be performed in the *same* order.

Comment: @Evg: as for your `liftA2 (==) l r`, this actually is extactly the same, you *first* will evaluate `l` and *then* you evaluate `r`. Notice that the *check* here is the victim. If you would use a `State` monad, you can the results more predictable and verify.

Comment: @Evg: in other words you make a recipe where you will first calculate `l`, then you calculate `r`, but meanwhile the "global system" state (likely) changes.

Comment: @Evg: in short, in both `l` and `r`, the actions `a1`, `a2` and `a3` will run in the same order. If these thus produce the same results, then the result will be the same. But something like `getUnixTime` depends on a *global* state; so then the result of `l` and `r` will simply be as unpredictable as `getUnixTime`. If you for example would "freeze" time, and after each time increment the clock, then it will return the same result for example.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It seems that with (liftA2 (==) l r) I try to test the internal value of IO for associativity :), but I must to test IO actions (not inner values), and they do not have EQ instance, so I can only to think of equality of them in context of freezed time as you said (or plus all state of the world).

Comment: Your `getUnixTime` example doesn't produce `False` because the order in which the `mappend` calls are evaluated, but because the uses of `getUnixTime` in `l` and `r` aren't executed simultaneously. None of the definitions of `a1`, `a2`, or `a3` actually *get* a time; they are just IO actions that, when executed, will get the time and pass the result to `show`. That won't actually happen until you try to execute the result of `liftA2 (==) l r` (which *also* only creates a new IO action without actually executing anything yet).

Comment: @chepner my misunderstanding was not in order, I expect associativity for wrong things) monoid fix associativity for actions, not for internal IO values. Actions a=a equal in any world. But to get values we need to provide world for actions and perform them, internal values of actions became same only if worlds are same. (a,w1) != (a,w2) but (a,w1) == (a,w1).

Comment: so no one answered the "why have it as a monoid then?" part. my guess is, so we can e.g. call `mconcat :: [IO a] -> IO a` to have a combined recipe that will `mconcat` the list of produced values.

Comment: The `Semigroup (IO a)` and `Monoid (IO a)` instances can be [derived via](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html?highlight=derivingvia#extension-DerivingVia) [`Ap IO a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Ap): `deriving via Data.Monoid.Ap IO a instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (IO a)` ... `deriving via Ap IO a instance Monoid a => Monoid (IO a)`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`` a1 `mappend` (a2 `mappend` a3) `` does not run in the order `a2`, `a3` and `a1`. In contrast to imperative languages like Python for example, in Haskell an `IO a` is not some *result* of a computation, it is a *recipe* to produce a value of `a`. You can actually see an `IO` more like a continuation in Python, you pass a function such that eventually it can be called, but you do not call it directly.

The `mappend` function is implemented as `liftA2 (<>)` for the `Semigroup a => Semigroup (IO a)` instance, as we can see in the [source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-482):

> ```
> instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (IO a) where
>     (<>) = liftA2 (<>)
> ```

This thus means that `mappend` is implemented as:

```
mappendIO :: Semigroup a => IO a -> IO a -> IO a
mappendIO f g = do
    x <- f
    y <- g
    pure (x <> y)
```

so it runs `f` before `g`.

If we now look at `` (a1 `mappend` a2) `mappend` a3 ``, we see:

```
(a1 `mappend` a2) `mappend` a3 = do
    x <- do
        x1 <- a1
        x2 <- a2
        pure (x1 <> x2)
    y <- a3
    pure (x <> y)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
(a1 `mappend` a2) `mappend` a3 = do
    x1 <- a1
    x2 <- a2
    x3 <- a3
    pure ((x1 <> x2) <> x3)
```

If we then look at `` a1 `mappend` (a2 `mappend` a3) `` then this is equivalen to:

```
a1 `mappend` (a2 `mappend` a3) = do
    x <- a1
    y <- do
        y1 <- a2
        y2 <- a2
        pure (y1 <> y2)
    pure (x <> y)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
a1 `mappend` (a2 `mappend` a3) = do
    x1 <- a1
    x2 <- a2
    x3 <- a2
    pure (x1 <> (x2 <> x3))
```

Since `x1 <> (x2 <> x3)` is equivalent to `(x1 <> x2) <> x3`, this will thus return the *same* result in both items.

As for your test:

```
l = (a1 `mappend` a2) `mappend` a3
r = a1 `mappend` (a2 `mappend` a3)
liftA2 (==) l r
False
```

Notice that the `liftA2 (==)` again will *define a sequence*, so that means that your `liftA2 (==) l r` is defined as:

```
liftA2 (==) l r = do
    x1 <- a1
    x2 <- a2
    x3 <- a3
    y1 <- a1
    y2 <- a2
    y3 <- a3
    pure ((x1 <> x2) <> x3) == (y1 <> (y2 <> y3))
```

You thus run `r` *after* `l`.

If you make use of `State` monad, you can make it more clear what will happen, and validate if the rule is applied. You need to *reset* the state between `l` and `r` however.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily bring up laziness; I don't think it's terribly relevant. And I certainly wouldn't lead with it!

Answer (score 7):

You cannot use `liftA2 (==)` to meaningfully compare IO values: this comparison relation is not even reflexive!

Indeed, if we run

```
a1 = show <$> getUnixTime 
liftA2 (==) a1 a1
```

It is possible to get a `False` result, since time passes between the two calls to `getUnixTime`, so the returned value might differ.

This is even more clear if you define `a1` to return the value of some random number generator. Calling that twice would yield a different result almost always.

Yet another example: `liftA2 (==) getLine getLine` can return false if the user enters two different lines.

When we say that `ioAction1` is equal to `ioAction2` we mean that they would have the same effect if executed in the exact same context. This is not the same as executing one action *after* the other and comparing the results.

Precisely defining "same IO effect" is tricky, though, since we usually want yo ignore performance differences. E.g. `return () >> print True` might be slightly slower than `print True`, if no optimization is performed, still we want to regard these two actions as having the same effects.